# I want to find some strings/words from column 1 and 2 in file1 that match column 1 in file2 and replace with column 2 strings/words in file2

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I'm still learning coding using Linux platform. I have search for problems similar to mine but the once I found they were either specific or focusing only on changing the entire column 1.

Here are example of my files:

File 1

```
abc Gamma 3.44
bcd abc 5.77
abc Alpha 1.99
beta abc 0.88
bcd Alpha 5.66
```

File 2

```
Gamma Bacteria
Alpha Bacteria
Beta Bacteria
```

Output file3

```
abc Bacteria 3.44
bcd abc 5.77
abc Bacteria 1.99
Bacteria abc 0.88
bcd Bacteria 5.66
```

I have tried:
awk:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2;next} {if ($1,$2 in a){$1,$2=a[$1,$2]}; print $0}' file2 file1
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[FNR]=$0; next} /$1|$2/ {$1 $2=a[FNR]} 1' file2 file1
```

They gave me:

```
abc Gamma 3.44
abc 5.77
abc Alpha 1.99
Bacteria abc 0.88
bcd Alpha 5.66
```

Only changing the $1 and remove the other text strings in column 1 which are not found in file2 $2

And this one:

```
$ awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t' 'FNR==1 { next }FNR == NR { file2[$1,$2] = $1 FS $2 } FNR != NR { file1[$1,$2,] = $1 FS $2} END { print "Match:"; for (k in file1) if (k in file1) print file2[k] # Or file1[k]}' file2 file1
```

Didn't work

Then after i tried sed:

```
$ sed = file2 | sed -r 'N;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\1s|\&$|\2|/' | sed -f - file1
```

This gave me an error and complained about
sed -e not being called properly.

Then after take only the smallest $3 if $1 and $2 or $2 and $1 are similar

file 4

```
bcd abc 5.77
Bacteria abc 0.88
bcd Bacteria 5.66
```

I have tried this code:

```
$ awk 'NR == $1&$2 || $3 < min {line = $0; min = $3}END{print line}' file3
$ awk '/^$1/{if(h){print h RS m}min=""; h=$0; next}min=="" || $3 < min{min=$3; m=$0}END{print h RS m}' file3
$ awk -F'\t' '$3 != "NF==min"' OFS='\t' file3
$ awk -v a=NODE '{c=a*$3+(1-a)} !($1 in min) || c<min[$1]{min[$1]=c; minLine[$1]=$0} END{for(k in minLine) print minLine[k]}' file3 | column -t
```

All didn't work and i tried to research what what does each line means and changed it to fit my problem. But they all failed

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's#(.*) (.*)#/^\1 /Is/\\S+/\2/;/^\\S+ \1 /Is/\\S+/\2/2#' file2 |
sed -Ef - file1
```

Generate a sed script from file2 which is run against file1 to produce the required format.

Comment: I tried the sed script i get this error: sed:  file - line 172: unknown command: `2'

Comment: @David does file2 have anything other than words in it?

Comment: Yes the file2 column has the species names as "Escherichia~coli~2" and also the file1 in both column 1 and 2 they are like that

Comment: @David what about at line 172? It may be that some characters may have to be escaped as they appear in a regexp.

Comment: Line 172 has "Enterobacteria~sp~DT571/2" would in be complaining about that "/2"